# Maximum Likelihood Problems - exercise

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I am working on a MLE question to find $\lambda$ where x has the distribution:

$$\lambda^2e^{-2\lambda x^2}$$

This is what I have done:
$$L(\lambda)=\prod{\lambda^2e^{-2\lambda x^2}}$$
$$=\lambda^{2n}e^{\sum-2\lambda x^2}$$
$$\log L(\lambda)=2n \log \lambda+\sum(-2\lambda x^2)$$
$$\frac{d \log L(\lambda)}{d(\lambda)}=\frac{2n}{\lambda}+\sum(-2 x^2)=0$$
$$\frac{2n}{\lambda}=-\sum(-2 x^2)$$
$$\frac{2n}{\lambda}=2n-\sum{x^2}$$
$$\lambda=-\sum{x^2}$$

May I ask is the answer correct please??

Comment: How exactly did you proceed after $$ \frac{2n}{\lambda}=-\sum(-2 x^2)\ \mathrm ?$$

Comment: um...I think I have made a mistake...thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I will place my answer here. Math1000 is correct, the derivation should be
$$ \frac{2n}{\lambda} = - \sum - 2x^2 $$
$$ \frac{n}{\lambda} = \sum x^2 $$
$$ \hat{\lambda} = \frac{n}{\sum x^2} $$

Comment: OK i see...thanks

Comment: It is good practice to check (e.g. by second derivative test) that $\hat\lambda$ is indeed a local maximum of the log-likelihood function :)